# How to get the count of distinct values from a relation in Prisma?

Tags: javascript, count, distinct, nest, prisma

I have a Student schema in relation to subject Schema as

Student -> Subjects

How do I get the total number of students per subject

For example

Student 1
{
id: 1
subjects :{
Chemistry, Biology
}
}

Student 2
{
id: 2
subjects :{
Maths
}
}

Student 3
{
id: 3
subjects :{
Chemistry, Maths
}
}

I want my final result to look like

| Subject | Students Enrolled |
| --- | --- |
| Chemistry | 2 |
| Maths | 2 |
| Biology | 1 |

```js
    const subjectMap = await this.prisma.subject.groupBy({
      by: ['subject'],
      _count: true,
      orderBy: {
        _count: {
          subject: 'desc',
        },
      },
    });
```